# Finding NDK on my System

Tags: android-ndk

I am following this tutorial and am stuck on Step 3 where I have to add in the NDK. What exactly is the NDK and where do I find it?

http://blog.guillaumeagis.eu/setup-andengine-with-android-studio/#comment-1535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also download the NDK using the SDK Manager I believe. There should be an option that says Android SDK and you can download it from within Android Studio if you are using it

Answer (score 1):

> what is Ndk?

Ndk is a toolset which would enable you to implement parts of your app into native languages such as C or C++.

> where you can download it?

http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

NDK is the Android Native development kit. You can download it from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).